# Android webapp won't open PDF on a https domain

Tags: android, pdf, web-applications, https, download

The pdf isn't on the server yet, but is created on the run. The URL would look like `https://mydomain.com/?pdf=example&params=abc`. If I open it in the desktop Browser, the PDF is shown. But on the mobile phone, it won't alawys start downloading, and if it does, the file is not readable. In the LogCat I get the following error:
`hostname mydomain.com was not verified`.

I've seen that other people have stumpled over the same error message, but unfortunately they're all writing in Java, and as im developing a web app I don't have the possibility to write Java code to fix the problem. Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could locate the problem. The certificate is only valid for `https://www.mydomain.com`, while I was trying to get the pdf without the `www` in the link. When I changed this, it worked. May be helpful for someone else with the same problem.